# Polyfill and MS Edge: How to get event functions from DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, polyfills

I'm using webcomponents to do some stuff. The webcomponents loader loads polyfill js files if it is detecting MS Edge. The moment the polyfill js files are loaded, I'm unable to get for example the `onchange` functions from an element.

If I run `var fnOnChange = document.getElementById('elementId').onchange;`, the result is `undefined`. Whereas without polyfills the result is for example `function onchange(event) { console.log('changed'); }`.

The onchange event (or onclick for that matter) itself triggers on an input when I type something and leave the input, but I have no chance of getting the function itself.

I know that polyfill wraps native elements and that they should behave like the native elements, but that this is not possible seems strange.

What did I miss?

Comment: Could it be because of the polfill breaking it never actually assigns the function to onchange?

Comment: Well the events do work. It's just, that I can't access them. But I need to get the functions at runtime.